# MongoDB commenting system Slug, What is it for?

Tags: mongodb, slug

I'm reading a tutorial on MongoDB on how to model the DB for commenting system [in here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/storing-comments/). 
One comment document has the following information:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    discussion_id: ObjectId(...),
    parent_id: ObjectId(...),
    slug: '34db/8bda'
    full_slug: '2012.02.08.12.21.08:34db/2012.02.09.22.19.16:8bda',
    posted: ISODateTime(...),
    author: {
              id: ObjectId(...),
              name: 'Rick'
             },
    text: 'This is so bogus ... '
}
```

What I can't seem to understand is what the `slug` and `full_slug` are for, can't understand it from the document.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For my opinion, it looks like some kind of a URL shortcut to get the comments, for example, when you type: 
`http://site.com/34db/8bda` it will bring you the comment itself, the `full-slug` is for sorting and ordering the comments by the time they posted.

Comment: Is there a way to generate these slugs?

Comment: I found this git, maybe it will help you generating slugs: https://github.com/crowdint/slugoid

Comment: IMHO the slug example is too small for real world if it acts as alternative unique key.

Comment: The `full_path` slug looks like a [Materialized Path Tree](https://dzone.com/articles/materialized-paths-tree-structures-relational-database) path value.
It should be build by using `parent_id` document `full_path` value and adding this document creation date and id. As udidu said, it is used for sorting discussion threads by messages replied to and comment date.

Answer (score 9):

Basically a slug is nothing more than a "part of a URL which identifies" an object "using human-readable keywords" (see [Wikipedia "Semantic URL"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL))

In the [MongoDB use case document "Storing Comments"](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/) each comment gets a unique short "slug part" which can be considered as a kind of alternative, database independent ID. The `slug` field of the comment document is then built by chaining all slug parts of all comments alongside the discussion thread hierarchy to form a path to the actual comment. Basically it could also be built by joining the string representations of the IDs of all (parent) comments delimited by slashes. But then it would be much longer, less human readable and to some degree more dependent from the underlying MongoDB database.

The `full_slug` field is formed like the `slug` as described above but each slug part is prefixed with the date and time of creation of its related comment. This seems to be necessary or at least advantageous to perform sorted queries by discussion thread and date at once. The `full_slug` field is arranged just for the implementation of queries sorted by discussion thread and date.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is like the answer above. But i think they have also another ussage.

For commenting system that required threaded comments (like reply to a comment), you need this "slug" stuffs in order to be able to sort the retrieved comments by 'full_slug'.

Resulted in an array of comments that sorted by threaded order. In the frontend, you can displayed them with different indent.

Answer (score 1):

A slug is a human-readable, unique identifier, used to identify a resource instead of a less human-readable identifier like an id . You use a slug when you want to refer to an item while preserving the ability to see, at a glance, what the item is.
These identifiers are then used in the URL.